# Why is "htmlspecialchars" so slow?

Tags: php, performance

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

... is about **2.5 times** slower than:

```
str_replace(array('&', '<', '>'), array('&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;'), $string);
```

Does [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) do something that the [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) line doesn't?

p.s. I measured speed in PHP 5.4, using [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.microtime.php).

Comment: @Juampi Take a stab at what ENT_NOQUOTES means...

Comment: Here's the source https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/html.c It has additional work with considering the charset beforehand, using different replacement sets instead of your fixed str_replace list, etc.

Comment: Also better use `strtr` than `str_replace`. But that's just a comment.

Comment: @hakre, Why? I read somewhere that `strtr` it is faster, but benchmarks that I did proved otherwise.

Comment: str_replace has the problem that you re-replace on the string. Which is not always wanted. in your case for example switching the first with the last replacement pair show you the issue. strtr does translation, str_replace does replacing. and if you're looking for speed, create a new PHP extension from C sources if you're looking for UTF-8 support: https://github.com/brianmario/escape_utils/tree/master/ext/escape_utils

Comment: Here is also a blog-post about that other lib and what speed has to do with it: https://github.com/blog/1475-escape-velocity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`str_replace()` treats strings as ASCII C-strings. `htmlspecialchars()` does not. (It's UTF8 strings by default in php 5.4, if memory serves.)

Also, there's code in `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid double-encoding, etc. It does more stuff.

Comment: Could you give an example of a case where it would be beneficial to use `htmlspecialchars` over `str_replace`?

Comment: Besides the double-encoding problems, there presumably are cases where `str_replace()` would happily accept invalid UTF8 strings whereas `htmlspecialchars()` probably wouldn't. Recollect why `mysql_real_escape_string()` was introduced back in the day: due to the potential for sql injections when you didn't worry about encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

The reason it is slower is because it does more. It handles various quotes, encodings and double encodings.

Working with encodings can be quite slow. Because computers are very fast it should not matter much, but if you compare it against a simple search and replace (which is basically all [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) does) it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that `htmlspecialchars()` has a parameter in which you can enter the charset you wish to use and it will also encode everything twice by default.